# Got ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound message while trying to retrieve data from other controller model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to build a site kind like news website. Users are able to post articles, and those articles would be classified into different categories, such as sports, politics...etc.

The thought was to have an index controller, which contains home/sports/politics...methods to make the url like xxx.com/index/home, xxx.com/index/sports. The home page will show every article. However I got the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound message when trying to get data.

There are 3 controllers so far. 
 1. Index 
 2. User (using devise)
 3. Post (with post model)

In Index controller:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
before_filter :find_post

def home
end

def find_post
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@posts = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

In post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :content, presence: true
end
```

the route.rb contains

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
resources :posts
```

while I ran /index/home page I got the message
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in IndexController#home
Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Extracted source (around line #39):
37  def find_post
38
39    @user = User.find(params[:id])

Comment: Can you also show the route for `index`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because params[:id] is empty because there's no id in the url. You should change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is expecting a User(id) and a Post(id) from the same variable (id)

To get the page to load, you would need to access it using:

```
/index/home/?id=1
```

The problem is though, that you are looking up your Posts and Users by the same parameter.  You probably were looking for this:

```
@posts = @user.posts
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is trying to get the User by the id that is passed in the url for the home action. Since you are using devise, you can get the current signed in user by using the `current_user` helper method. If there is no signed in User, then `current_user` will return `nil`.

Your code also seems to want to set `@posts` as the User's posts, filtered by the index type. Assuming that you have an `index_type` attribute set in the Post model, you could get the posts that belong to that user like this:

```
def home
  @posts = set_posts
end

def sports
  @posts = set_posts("sports")
end

private
def set_posts(type = %w{sports politics other})
  current_user.posts.where(index_type: type)
end
```